# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space in allocating array size

Tags: java, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I am doing very small program in java using Eclipse Kepler IDE.

I am allocating the size of the array at run time using the following statement.

```
unSortedArray = new int[sizeRow][sizeColumn];
```

so as per my knowledge the java program runs with some of its own heap space like 32 MB.

And for my program i think this space is enough.

I just given the value `sizeRow=3` and `sizeColumn=3` at runtime.

And when i pressed enter it gives the following Exception **`java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`**

I put this question to understand why it happens and how we can handle it?

I already read the following link.

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

[How to deal with "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" error (64MB heap size)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap)

**EDIT:1**

```
public class ArraySort
{
private int[][]                 unSortedArray;
private int                     sizeColumn, sizeRow;

private final DataInputStream   dataInputStream = new DataInputStream(
                                                        System.in);

public boolean getArraySize() throws IOException
{
    try
    {
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the row:");
        sizeRow = (dataInputStream.readInt());
        System.out.print("Enter the size of the column:");
        sizeColumn = dataInputStream.readInt();
        return false;
    }
    catch (NumberFormatException e)
    {
        System.out.println("Enter valid value for size:");
    }
    return true;
}

public boolean getArrayElement() throws IOException
{
    unSortedArray = new int[sizeRow][sizeColumn];
    for (int i = 0; i < sizeRow; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < sizeColumn; j++)
        {
            try
            {
                System.out.println("Enter Element [" + i + "," + j + "]");
                unSortedArray[i][j] = dataInputStream.readInt();
            }
            catch (NumberFormatException ne)
            {
                System.out
                        .println("Enter proper Numeric value for Array Element");
                return true;
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}
}


public class ArraySortProgram
{

public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    ArraySort arraySort = new ArraySort();

    arraySort.getArraySize();
    arraySort.getArrayElement();
}
}
```

**In my case i am calling these method only once.**

Comment: these kind of errors can not be handled, but I am not sure why this is happening, can you post complete code once.

Comment: So you create a 3x3 array of `int`s and get an OOME right after? Really?

Comment: yeah..this seems like sun revolving around earth :P but there has to be some catch!!

Comment: @Vidya yeah that is what i mean to say.

Comment: Could you please post some code? Are you sure you are initializing the array with those values?

Comment: The IDE you are using is not relevant.

Comment: @Batty here is the code.

Comment: `google` is searching for answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems is here:

```
dataInputStream.readInt()
```

This would read a binary value from your input which would be like 2323827382 for your entered "1251" causing the OOM.

Try to use `Scanner` to read your integers like this:

```
public class ArraySort{
    private final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    int sizeRow, sizeColumn;

    public boolean getArraySize() throws IOException
    {
        try
        {
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the row:");
            sizeRow = (scanner.nextInt());
            System.out.print("Enter the size of the column:");
            sizeColumn = scanner.nextInt();
            return false;
        }
        catch (NumberFormatException e)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter valid value for size:");
        }
        return true;
    }    
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If the offending code is as you have shown us, then there are possibilities:

- Previous to executing this statement, you have allocated other objects and you have consumed *nearly all* of the available space in doing so.  This statement is the proverbial straw that breaks the camel's back.
- The values of `sizeRow` and `sizeColumn` are NOT what you think they are.

We cannot distinguish between these two possibilities without seeing more of your code.

---

**UPDATE** - Andrey has found the problem, based on your updated code.  You are reading the sizes incorrectly, resulting in incorrect / very large size values.  That is causing your application to try to allocate a HUGE array of arrays ... which is giving the OOME.

Comment: ya you are right but in my case i am calling these method only once.

Comment: See EDIT in my question.