# Adding compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1' in Gradle causes OUT OF MEMORY error

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

This is my Gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 21
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.googleplus_1"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'
}

/*
configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support'
}

configurations {
    all*.exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-v4'
    all*.exclude group: 'com.google.android.gms', module: 'play-services'
}*/
```

When I Run the app I get this error:

```
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL ERROR:
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
```

however If I comment "compile 'com.google.gdata:core:1.47.1'" and the relevant code the error is gone.

Can you please help me out with this? Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335/how-to-deal-with-java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space-error-64mb-heap

Comment: I guess these are not related. My code is minimal and should not cause the out of memory issue at the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see you imported the whole play services api. In the documentation, it says you should use the dependencies for the specific apis you need, like google maps api.

http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html