# "java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" for adding elements into array

Tags: java, performance, out-of-memory, heap-memory

I get "Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space" exception while adding values in arrayList. This is just a example

```
public class Test     {

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Test t= new Test();
        ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> deleteError = new  ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();
        for(TableItem item : items) // loop moves 800 times
        {
            for(String Element_ID : checkelementID) // another loop which check element ids which moves for 800 again
            {
                t.deleteErrorInArrayList("1", "GEN_err", "11", deleteError);
                t.deleteErrorInArrayList("1", "Greater_than", "11", deleteError);

                t.deleteErrorInArrayList("1", "GEN_err", "16", deleteError);
                t.deleteErrorInArrayList("1", "Greater_than", "16", deleteError);
            }
        }


    }
    public void deleteErrorInArrayList(String rowID,String message,String column,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mainlist)
    {
        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.add(rowID);
        list.add(message);
        list.add(column);
        mainlist.add(list);
        list = null;
    }
}
```

Please help me. How to optimize above code so i can reduce time and remove exception.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

Answer (score 0):

Given that all elements of the inner lists have the same structure (three strings), you could do better by storing an array (`String[]`) instead of an ArrayList.

Further: you are wasting space by storing strings, when you (apparently) only need some codes.
I'd try replaceing `GEN_err` and `Greater_than` by some integer encoding, and store arrays of three integers (or shorts, or bytes) instead and you should use less memory.

Comment: But i haven't pre-defined size for String[]. Data might be increased or decreased.

Comment: Well, it's hard for us to give tips for optimizing some code if you don't give us the specs (only code).

Comment: I think I have given entire main class just to understand the scenario. Let me know if anything else you required.

Comment: I have already given two suggestions, they depend on whether you can 1) replace strings by integer codes, and 2) assume all sublists have sizes 3 - your code does not (cannot) make that clear, you must state that.