# Increase HeapSize in Tomcat for all my applications

Tags: java, tomcat, docker, war

I'm using a tomcat:8 inside docker.
This are some important settings (default).

```
$ java -XX:+PrintFlagsFinal -version | grep -iE 'HeapSize|PermSize|ThreadStackSize'
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/jboss -Duser.name=jboss
     intx CompilerThreadStackSize                   = 0                                   {pd product}
    uintx ErgoHeapSizeLimit                         = 0                                   {product}
    uintx HeapSizePerGCThread                       = 87241520                            {product}
    uintx InitialHeapSize                          := 33554432                            {product}
    uintx LargePageHeapSizeThreshold                = 134217728                           {product}
    uintx MaxHeapSize                              := 524288000                           {product}
     intx ThreadStackSize                           = 1024                                {pd product}
     intx VMThreadStackSize                         = 1024                                {pd product}
```

Now I need to increase the max heapsize because I get some problems with `outofmemory` issues. (The applications are pretty heavy).

Before it goes out of memory it's warning me that the max heapsize is nearly reached and that the tomcat will go `outofmemory`. A few minutes later it's crashing.

Inside my tomcat are a couple of `.war`'s deployed.
The apps are in `/deployments/xxx.war`.

`ls` shows me

```
app1_0.1                                               
app1_0.1.war                                           
app2_0.1                                       
app2_0.1.war
...
```

Now my question is the following. Do I have to increase the heapsize for every .war file seperatly or for the whole tomcat at the same moment.
Because I don't find a command to check the heapsize on one java application but when I want to increase the heapsize I only seem to find command like this: `java -Xms16m -Xmx64m ClassName` (so on one specific application).

When I just execute it without specifying an app:

```
$ java -Xms16m -Xmx64m
Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Duser.home=/home/jboss -Duser.name=jboss
Usage: java [-options] class [args...]
           (to execute a class)
   or  java [-options] -jar jarfile [args...]
           (to execute a jar file)
where options include:
    -d32      use a 32-bit data model if available
    -d64      use a 64-bit data model if available
    -server   to select the "server" VM
                  The default VM is server,
                  because you are running on a server-class machine.
...
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at related SE question regarding solutions for `OutOfMemory` errors

[java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space)

`MaxPermSize` flag has been removed with JDK 1.8. It was replaced by `Metaspace`.

**JDK8: Metaspace**

In JDK 8, classes metadata is now stored in the native heap and this space is called `Metaspace`. There are some new flags added for `Metaspace` in JDK 8:

`-XX:MetaspaceSize=<NNN>` where  is the initial amount of space(the initial high-water-mark) allocated for class metadata (in bytes) that may induce a garbage collection to unload classes.

`-XX:MaxMetaspaceSize=<NNN>` where  is the maximum amount of space to be allocated for class metadata (in bytes).

Have a look at oracle [blog](https://blogs.oracle.com/poonam/entry/about_g1_garbage_collector_permanent)

Use `-d64`  option in VM parameters since you are using 64 bit OS.

VM parameters you are setting is global to tomact instance.

Answer (score 0):

Try increasing the perm size as well:
-XX:MaxPermSize=256m

This will add 256mb to your heap size when your app needs it.

Comment: Can you give me the exact command? I tried `java -XX:MaxPermSize=256m` but didn't work: `OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM warning: ignoring option MaxPermSize=256m; support was removed in 8.0`

Comment: JDK 8 requires that you manage meta space.  Perm gen has gone away.