# How to allocate more memory? java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space

Tags: java, memory, heap-memory

System:
Ubuntu 18.04.6 LTS, Intel Core i9-9900K, 128 GB
DDR4 RAM

I am supposed to run this line:

```
./bin/jre/bin/java -cp lib/fcc-deploy-archive.jar de.fiskal.connector.init.UpdateCLIApplication
```

I get this error message after 9 seconds:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space
    at java.util.Arrays.copyOf(Arrays.java:3236) ~[?:1.8.0_275]
```

I tried to allocate (alot) more memory by using the `-XmX` like this:

```
./bin/jre/bin/java -Xmx64g -cp lib/fcc-deploy-archive.jar de.fiskal.connector.init.UpdateCLIApplication
```

How can I test if the option can be set at all? What else could be the problem here?

Comment: Set -Xms to the same value as -Xmx. Then, the JVM will try to allocate the heap immediately.

Comment: For long running applications, do not set -Xms the same to -Xmx, it will disable a number of heuristics that might help with performance. Also, setting -Xms to -Xmx will not prevent a OutOfMemoryError if -Xmx is too low.

Comment: As an aside, if the option couldn't be set, you'd receive an error. That doesn't mean that using 64g might not result in swapping or other effects bad for performance if it actually ends up using 64GiB.

Comment: It's not really long running. I get that error after 9 seconds. It's just an update process that has to run once somehow.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, do you have any sources regarding the optimization tradeoffs? I'm asking because in the past Oracle recommended to set Xms and Xmx to an equal value.

Comment: @Mihe _"Setting -Xms and -Xmx to the same value increases predictability by removing the most important sizing decision from the virtual machine. However, the virtual machine is then unable to compensate if you make a poor choice."_ from https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/vm/gctuning/sizing.html

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, thanks. Of course, if one allocates too much, it's a bad thing. On the other hand, Oracle recommended the same value to decrease the number of GCs.

Comment: @Mihe The reality is more nuanced. Yes, setting them equal will avoid a number of full-gc, increase heap, full gc, increase heap, etc, but it also disables a number of tuning heuristics around sizing generations, which could result in worse performance than if you had - for example - set -Xms to half of -Xmx.

Answer (score 0):

**Following is for Eclipse**

Right mouse click on

Run As - Run Configuration - Arguments - Vm Arguments,
then add this

-Xmx2048m

Answer (score 0):

as stated already [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1596009/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-java-heap-space) you can use the `-Xms` and `-Xmx` parameters to allocate more memory to the heap of the JVM, but keep in mind that if your machine doesn't have the amount of RAM that you provided in these parameters it will not work.

Comment: Thank you, I tried this (`-Xms64g -Xmx64g`) with all kind of numbers (from 512m to 64g). I still get the error message.